# Creating Data Frame from RDD - PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am not able to show the DataFrame where while creating DF from the existing RDD by providing the required schema while executing PySpark code the below exception raised this code is executed in the Databricks community platform. please help with the solution to show the data frame as output.

code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('RDD2DF')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

rdd=sc.textFile('/FileStore/tables/StudentData.csv')
header = rdd.first()
rdd2df= rdd.filter(lambda x: x!=header).map(lambda x: x.split(','))

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

scehma = StructType([
                    StructField('age', StringType(),True),
                    StructField('gender',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('name',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('course',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('roll',IntegerType(),True),
                    StructField('marks',IntegerType(),True),
                    StructField('email',StringType(),True)
])

columns = header.split(',')
rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2df, schema)
rdf.printSchema()
rdf.show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1654966391766461> in <module>
     22 rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2df, schema)
     23 rdf.printSchema()
---> 24 rdf.show()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    488         """
    489         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 490             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    491         else:
    492             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5174.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 50.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 50.0 (TID 53) (ip-10-172-163-248.us-west-2.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: field age: IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>'. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 713, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 705, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 267, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 729, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1390, in verify_struct
    verifier(v)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1329, in verify_integer
    verify_acceptable_types(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1291, in verify_acceptable_types
    raise TypeError(new_msg("%s can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: field age: IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:795)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:812)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:815)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2712)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:512)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3018)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3810)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2742)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3802)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2742)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2949)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:343)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: field age: IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>'. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 713, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 705, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 267, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 729, in prepare
    verify_func(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1390, in verify_struct
    verifier(v)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1409, in verify
    verify_value(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1329, in verify_integer
    verify_acceptable_types(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1291, in verify_acceptable_types
    raise TypeError(new_msg("%s can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: field age: IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:795)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:812)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1643)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:815)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: See that you are defining `scehma` variable but later you use `schema` in here: `rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2df, schema)`.

Error `TypeError: field age: IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>` means that you are trying to use string variable in Integer field. 
So it seems that you defined previously schema with age as IntegerType in *schema* which you use instead of wrongly spelled *scehma* which you defined with correct StringType.

Comment: @Pav3k I tried by correcting the typo 'scehma' to 'schema' but still error remain the same as below
 ''TypeError: field marks: IntegerType can not accept object '59' in type <class 'str'>''

Comment: Why do you have to use RDD in the first place? You can just read CSV directly, skip header and pass the schema

Comment: @pltc I am giving a try to convert RDD to DF where I am aware of the method without creating RDD but in the exploration of alternative methods of usage and  I am new to data bricks environment hence tried and got output where it's more clear to understand Databricks environment for PySpark cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pav3k Thanks for the reply and you notified typo in my code that is one of the reasons for the exception by the way I found the solution for the
`**IntegerType can not accept object '28' in type <class 'str'>**` is where I am trying to change the schema of the existing RDD after creating DataFrame while using existing RDD we should cast the required datatypes like
code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('RDD2DF')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

rdd=sc.textFile('/FileStore/tables/StudentData.csv')
header = rdd.first()
rdd2df= rdd.filter(lambda x: x!=header).map(lambda x: x.split(','))
rddc = rdd2df.map(lambda x: [int(x[0]),x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],int(x[5]),x[6]])
rddc.collect()`
```

after casting RDD then we should provide a schema for DataFrame to change the required data type as specified in the below code.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
                    StructField('age', IntegerType(),True),
                    StructField('gender',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('name',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('course',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('roll',StringType(),True),
                    StructField('marks',IntegerType(),True),
                    StructField('email',StringType(),True)
])

columns = header.split(',')
rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rddc, schema)
rdf.printSchema()
rdf.show()
```

Finally, I got the output after finding a typo in my code and Databricks PySpark cluster environment requirement because when we execute PySpark code in Databricks some clusters automatically consider RDD datatype.

Ouput:

```
rdf:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
age:integer
gender:string
name:string
course:string
roll:string
marks:integer
email:string
```